# Trouble outputting complex array/object data with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dynamic, business-catalyst

I am currently working on a page that compiles dynamic data from web app submissions in the Business Catalyst content management system. BC allows you to create webapps that output tags in the form of {tag_itemid} these tags are essentially variables that the system outputs in the form of the information it represents.

That said I have a page that is very complex and pulls data from several webapps to output it into generated divs that the user can view. I am having some trouble, however with the page reading my array. I keep receiving an error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [' The error appears at the start of my array, allQuestions{tag_itemid}[0] .

For now, ignore the BC tags, they don't really affect the script. There are WebApp tags that fill in the gaps you might see with the variables I am passing into my array.

If you could take a look at my code and tell me why I am getting the error I would be grateful, I've tried to include all of the relevant information without overloading you with code. Also just note that the variables are all defined on the page or above the pieces I have shared with you - I'm not receiving any undefined errors.

Thanks for any and all help!

```
var questionAnswers{tag_itemid} = function(qNum, ACount, BCount, CCount, DCount, TCount, FCount, answerType, Rating, SAnswer, qText) {
    this.qNum = qNum;
    this.ACount = ACount;
    this.BCount = BCount;
        this.CCount = CCount;
        this.DCount = DCount;
        this.TCount = TCount;
        this.FCount = FCount;
        this.Rating = Rating;
        this.SAnswer = SAnswer;
        this.answerType = answerType;
        this.avgAnswer = 0;
        this.avgAnswerText = "";
        this.formatSAnswers = function() {
            var x = this.SAnswer
            var y = x.join('"</p></div><div class="sAnswer-data"><p>"');
            this.avgAnswer = y;
            };
        this.qavgAnswer = function() {
            if (this.answerType != "" || this.anserType != " ") {
                if (this.answerType == "Multiple Choice") {
                    if (this.ACount > this.BCount && this.ACount > this.CCount && this.ACount > this.DCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "A was selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times";
                    } else if (this.BCount > this.ACount && this.BCount > this.CCount && this.BCount > this.DCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.BCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "B was selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times";
                    } else if (this.CCount > this.ACount && this.CCount > this.BCount && this.CCount > this.DCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.CCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "C was selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times";
                    } else if (this.DCount > this.ACount && this.DCount > this.BCount && this.DCount > this.CCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.DCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "D was selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times";
                    } else if (this.ACount == this.Dcount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAsnwerText = "Both A and D selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.ACount == this.Bcount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAsnwerText = "Both A and B selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.ACount == this.Ccount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAsnwerText = "Both A and C selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.BCount == this.Acount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.BCount;
                        this.avgAsnwerText = "Both B and D selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.BCount == this.Ccount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.BCount;
                        this.avgAsnwerText = "Both B and C selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.CCount == this.Dcount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.CCount;
                        this.avgAsnwerText = "Both C and D selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.ACount == this.BCount && this.ACount == this.CCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "Answer A, B, and C were selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.ACount == this.CCount && this.ACount == this.DCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "Answer A, C, and D were selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.BCount == this.CCount && this.BCount == this.DCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.BCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "Answer B, C, and D were selected: " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.ACount == 0 && this.ACount == this.BCount && this.ACount == this.CCount && this.ACount == this.DCount) {
                        this.avgAnswerText = "There were no selections made for this question.";
                    } else {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.ACount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "All selections are equal. Answers A, B, C, and D were selected " + this.ACount + " times each.";
                    };
                    this.correctAText = "The correct answer:<br/><br/>" + this.avgAnswer;
                } else if (this.answerType == "True/False") {
                    if (this.TCount > this.FCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.TCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "True was selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.TCount < this.FCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.FCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "False was selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    } else if (this.TCount == 0 && this.TCount == this.FCount) {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.TCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "There is not enough data to calculate the average user-selected answer for this question.";
                    } else {
                        this.avgAnswer = this.TCount;
                        this.avgAnswerText = "Both True and False were selected " + this.avgAnswer + " times.";
                    };
                    this.correctAText = "The correct answer:<br/><br/>" + this.avgAnswer;
                } else if (this.answerType == "Ratings") {
                    this.correctAText = "This question is evaluated with survey ratings.";
                    this.Rating = this.Rating / ch{tag_itemid}_userCompletes;
                    this.avgAnswer = this.Rating;
                    this.avgAnswerText = "The average rating for this question is " + this.avgAnswer;
                } else {
                    this.correctAText = "This question is evaluated with survey short answers.";
                    this.formatSanswers();
                    this.avgAnswerText = 'This question is a short answer survey. Click the button below to see some of the answers.<br/><br/><a class="button small">View responses</a></p></div><div><p class="sAnswer-data">';
                };
            } else {
                this.avgAnswerText = "There is no data for this question. Please try again at a later time.";
            };
        };
            this.insertInfo = function(divID) {
              document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="small-12 columns" id="q' + this.qNum + '_text"><p><span class="qNum-data">' + this.qNum + '</span>' + this.qText + '</p></div><div class="row"><div class="small-12 medium-6 columns" id="qAvgAnser' + this.qNum + '"><p class="avgA-data">' + this.avgAnswerText + '</p></div><div class="small-12 medium-6 columns"><p class="avgA-data">' + this.correctAnswer + '</p></div></div></div>';
            };

            this.showData = function() {
                resource = document.createElement('div');
                addID = document.createAttribute("id");
                divName = "ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}_q" + this.qNum;
                addID.value = divName;
                resource.setAttributeNode(addClass);
                insertInfo(divName);
            };
            this.generateInfo(passedDivID) = function() {
                passedDivID = passedDivID + this.showData();
        };
    };
```

Note that here is the actual array, I have limited it to 4 elements as opposed to the 15 it actually holds.

```
    var allQuestions{tag_itemid} = [];
    var allQuestions{tag_itemid}[0] = questionAnswers{tag_itemid}("1", ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QAavg1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QBavg1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QCavg1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QDavg1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QTavg1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QFavg1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}qAType1, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}Rate1Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}SA1Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QText1);
    var allQuestions{tag_itemid}[1] = questionAnswers{tag_itemid}("2", ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QAavg2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QBavg2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QCavg2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QDavg2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QTavg2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QFavg2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}qAType2, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}Rate2Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}SA2Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QText2);
    var allQuestions{tag_itemid}[2] = questionAnswers{tag_itemid}("3", ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QAavg3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QBavg3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QCavg3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QDavg3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QTavg3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QFavg3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}qAType3, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}Rate3Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}SA3Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QText3);
    var allQuestions{tag_itemid}[3] = questionAnswers{tag_itemid}("4", ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QAavg4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QBavg4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QCavg4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QDavg4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QTavg4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QFavg4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}qAType4, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}Rate4Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}SA4Q, ch{tag_itemid}_ch{tag_chapter number}QText4);
```

And here is the script interacting with the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
        if (allQuestions[i].qText != "" || allQuestions[i].qText != " ") {
            allQuestions[i].qavgAnswer();
            allQuestions[i].generateInfo(quizDiv{tag_itemid});
        };
```

Comment: Your array is called `allQuestions{tag_itemid}` which I assume equates to something like `allQuestions10` for example, but you're only referencing `allQuestions` in your loop. That might be a problem, maybe not the the same one tho.

Comment: Thank you for catching that Andy, I've corrected the name error but I am still getting the Uncaught Syntax error, same as before.

Comment: Can you add the actual HTML output after the server data has been added?

Comment: Hi Andy, it's over 135000 lines of code, is there any way you can tell me specifically which piece you're looking for? The containing div? The output of the array on the page? Thanks so much for your help!